# Partition data mid-job on Spring Batch

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, jobs

I want to create a job in spring data which should consist of two steps:

Step 1 - First step reads certain transactions from database and produces a list of record Ids that will be sent to step 2 via jobContext attribute.

Step 2 - This should be a partition step: The slave steps should be partitioned based on the list obtained from step 1 (each thread gets a different Id from the list) and perform their read/process/write operations without interfering with each other.

My problem is that even though I want to partition data based on the list produced by step 1, spring configures step 2 (and thus, calls the partitioner's partition() method) before step 1 even starts, so I cannot inject the partitioning criteria on time. I tried using @StepScope on the partitioner bean, but it still attempts to create the partitions before the job starts.

Is there a way to dynamically create the step partitions during runtime, or an alternative way to divide a step into threads based on the list provided by step 1?

---

Some background:

I am working on a batch job using spring batch which has to process Transactions stored in a database. Every transaction is tied to an Account (in a different table), which has an accountBalance that also needs to be updated whenever the transaction is processed.

Since I want to perform these operations using multi-threading, I thought a good way to avoid collisions would be to group transactions based on their accountId, and have each thread process only the transactions that belong to that specific accountId. This way, no two threads will attempt to modify the same Account at the same time, as their Transactions will always belong to different Accounts.

However, I cannot know which accountIds need to be processed until I get the list of transactions to process and extract the list from there, so I need to be able to provide the list to partition during runtime. Thtat's why I thought I could generate that list in a previous step, and then have the next step partition and process the data accordingly.

Is the approach I am taking plausible with this setup? Or should I just look for a different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to partition the data mid-job like I wanted, so I had to use this workaround:

Instead of dividing the job in two steps, I moved the logic from step 1 (the "setup step") into a service method that returns the list of transactions to process, and added a call to that method inside the partition() method in my partitioner, allowing me to create the partitions based on the returned list.

This achieves the same result in my case, although I'm still interested in knowing if it is possible to configure the partitions mid-job, since this solution would not work if I had to perform more complex processing or writing in the setup step and wanted to configure exception handling policies and such. It probably would not work either if the setup step was placed in the middle of a step chain instead of at the start.